# How to find location of first occurrence of NaT and NaN in 192 columns (each 80000 values) of Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of 192 columns x 80000 values. However, some of the columns have `NaN (Not a number)` and `NaT (Not a Time)`. How to find the location of their first occurance?> I tried my way as given below:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#df has 192 columns and each column has 80000 values
for i,j in zip(df.columns[::2],df.columns[1::2]):
    print(df[(str(df[i])=='NaT')].index,df[(str(df[j])=='NaN')].index)
```

Output is:

```
KeyError: False

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

For following modified code:

```
print(df[(df[i]=='NaT')].index,df[(df[j]=='NaN')].index)
```

I got output as:

```
Int64Index([], dtype='int64') Int64Index([], dtype='int64')
Int64Index([], dtype='int64') Int64Index([], dtype='int64')
Int64Index([], dtype='int64') Int64Index([], dtype='int64')
Int64Index([], dtype='int64') Int64Index([], dtype='int64')
Int64Index([], dtype='int64') Int64Index([], dtype='int64')
Int64Index([], dtype='int64') Int64Index([], dtype='int64')
Int64Index([], dtype='int64') Int64Index([], dtype='int64')
.
.
```

What is the mistake? why values did not appear here?

As per @ChrisA answer:

```
print(df[i].isna().idxmax(),df[j].isna().idxmax())
```

Output is:

```
83912 83912
83451 83451
83681 83681
83697 83697
83873 83873
83660 83660
82975 82975
83847 83847
0 0
83537 83537
83762 83762
.
```

Why is that it returned 0 for some columns in middle? Does it mean, first sample of those two columns is null? But actually those two columns have all values.

Comment: Use `pd.Series.isnull` as per marked duplicates, no string conversion required.

Comment: Use `df.isna().idxmax()` will give you the index of the first NaN for every column

Comment: @ChrisA, Thanks. Your method did work. But, did see the output ? Why is that it returned 0 for some columns in middle? Does it mean, first sample of those two columns is null? But actually those two columns have all values.

Comment: @Msquare good point. You could try: `df.isna().idxmax() * np.where(df.isna().any(), 1, np.nan)` 0 should now mean NaN at index 0 - NaN means no NaN values